# a Onclick or Onchange event for a select HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I got a question over here for you:-)

I've got a problem with a select with a onchange or onclick event.

I want to do, when a user clicks a specific select value, than a checkbox will appear in the div i made...

Here under can you see the code::
***This is the SELECT menu:***

```
<select id="pakket">
    <option value="">Kies uw bundel</option>
    <option value="internet">Internet</option>
    <option value="telefonie">Telefonie</option>
    <option value="allin">All-in-1</option>
</select>
<div id="telefoniecheck"></div>
```

So I want to do anything with Javascript, when a user clicks the value "Telefonie" or "allin" that a checkbox will appear in the div under my select.

Thanks in advance guys :-))

**EDIT**

I got it when I gave the select a onchange, and made a script with javascript with if/else.

When the value of 'pakket' == 'telefonie' than show a checkbox.

I'm always open to have better solutions!

Comment: You want to add an onchange event to the SELECT, which then checks the value of the selectedIndex (the option that was chosen). Then show the check box for the specific value(s).

Comment: So check the value after the element's change event has fired.

Comment: Obligatory question: what have you tried so far? To get you going, you want the onchange event for your `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
//do something with the value
var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag.

Comment: It was not anything related with jQuery, but thanks for thinking mate! I already solved it :)